# I have trouble understanding the use of 'this' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have trouble understanding how to use 'this' in the following code. I am creating circles with Raphael.js and Jquery.

```
$(function(){

    function circleAttributes(x, y, r){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
        this.strokeweight = 3;
        console.log(x,y,r, this.x);
    }
    var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 1200, 600);

    var circles = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        circles.push(new circleAttributes(Math.floor(Math.random() * 500), Math.floor(Math.random() * 500), 5));
        paper.circle(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, circles[i].r);
        console.log(circles);
    }

});
```

Everything is working fine this way, but if I change `this.x` to `circleAttributes.x` I can't seem to access x in the line `paper.circle(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, circles[i].r);`.

Do I write `circles[i].circleAttributes.x`? That doesn't seem to work either, but I feel like it should be able to! It should be just like saying `person.name` or?

I understand that 'this' is used like a pronoun 'he'. Mike is running away, because HE is scared.

Edit: I still don't understand it, please someone explain it in simple terms!

Comment: simply `this` refers to current function/object scope

Comment: But then this.x and circleAttributes.x are the same thing right?

Comment: @AustriaNotAustralia See `circleAttributes.x` would be global one while `this` will be your local/current object. So in es5 standards `this` is used to set properties for local objects. consider a loop which makes several objects and all those object would have different properties in terms of width, height, depth etc.

Comment: @AustriaNotAustralia if you are create an object of `circleAttributes` then you can access their property by 'YourObject.x' and inside `circleAttributes` you can access its property by `this.x`

Comment: @Jai But then why can I not declare x as `circleAttributes.x = x`? There is no other circleAttributes.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `'this'.property or 'this'.method` you are simply refering to the parent object initializing the action or function. It saves you time of writing it all over and when you make a chnage to the object name, id or the wildcard you use in calling it you don't have to change all line it appeared in between.

In jQuery when you have

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
//you can access the btn object like below
$(this).text('click me');
$(this).show();
});
```

Comment: Yes I understand that, so I should be able to write `$('#btn")` instead of `$(this)` right? But if I do that in my example, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you can make a simple hack by having the parameters passed to a public variable and retrieve them when accessing the function from another. Or create a statndard jQuery function with $.fn.circleAttributes = function(inputfld, boundfld)....

Answer (score 0):

"this" is not a pronoun ( if we consider pronoun as a pointer). "this" is object instance of function where its used.
circles[i].circleAttributes.x means you are trying to access circleAttributes.x inside circleAttributes function, that is you need to declare circleAttributes.circleAttributes.x to access it that way.

Comment: Ah, finally an answer that makes sense to me. So there is no way to declare `circleAttributes.x = x` and access it?

Comment: yes. ( you can nest it creating another variable and giving it x,y,z components, but that's another topic )